# How to use Delphi to sign REST requests using HMAC-SHA256

Tags: json, delphi, rest, hmac

I'm attempting to query an REST service with fairly limited idea of how to approach it.
I'm using Delphi XE6 (upd 1)

The company providing the API have said that: "The API is implemented as JSON via SSL"
 and they go on to say that:

> Access to any API endpoint requires authentication via signed requests, created with publicand secret API
>   keys

I have the keys defined above.

> The signature is an HMAC­SHA256 hash of a string containing the request content­type, host,
>   URL, date timestamp (matching the request Date header) and request content (eg POST
>   parameters) separated by a single newline, and passed with the public key in a custom header
>   X­API­Authorization along with the public key, in the format PUBLICKEY:SIGNATURE

I understand each request needs to be signed.

How do I sign an `http` request with Delphi XE6?

The confusion for me at the moment is it seems Delphi has a number of built-in components have accessing RSET servers and parsing the JSON returned. I can't see any obvious way of signing requests using these components.

Specifically is there any help from the built-in Rest components or do I have to provide my own solution?

Comment: Have you found an solution to this problem yet? I'm in the same situation.